# React native Android gives error about gradle

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

[image]

I am getting this error while running a code in Android, this is about gradle but I  already have added this thing in the build.gradle

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
```

Please help thanks in advance

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+' // <- USE 2.2.+ version
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Add jitpack repository (added by tipsi-stripe)
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

This is my build gradle where it is saying there is a problem in line 13

Comment: android/build.gradle line 13, please share your build.gradle because it says that the error is at line 13 of it.

Comment: Hello Cristian Please check the question I have uploaded the build.gradle

Comment: Check your gradle-wrapper.properties file and change distributionUrl to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip and try again

Comment: I have changed it but still getting error http://prntscr.com/llfc9t please check

Comment: Remove the last line with 2.14

Comment: Also please if it worked for you mark my answer as accepted https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your gradle-wrapper.properties file and change distributionUrl to

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: btw you need to remove this from your gradle file
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+' // <- USE 2.2.+ version
    }
for the error I would need to see your app/build.gradle but that's something for another question I guess.

Comment: I have kept it in comment but still the error is coming http://prntscr.com/llfgth

Comment: yes that's unrelated, I said because It could cause another problems and you wouldn't know, it conflicts with the other declaration

Comment: So what to do now?

Comment: You need to post another question for that, I would suggest to also add your app/build.gradle to that question, I know it's a burden but it's just the rules of SO, comments are not for this. Don't worry, you are on the right track.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184068/discussion-between-kedar-dave-and-cristian-gomez).